# FQL - How to retrieve list of friends who are added on/above particular date

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get the list of friends who are all added as friend on/above a particular date in FQL?

I am able to retrieve list of friends.  But I need more information like 'Friend added date' etc...

Please provide your thoughts or solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: No, this is not possible in a direct way – and that’s by design, because Facebook does not allow apps that promise to notify a user “when someone unfriends you” or something like that. The only – tedious – way to get this kind of info is by going to a user’s stream and look for all those messages saying “foo is now friends with bar” and hav a look at their creation time. But be warned, if you are trying to do anything with that info like apps I mentioned before, Facebook might most likely kick your app very quickly.

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you very much.  I tried the similar thing and get succeeded to get new friend alert.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the newly added friend using FQL.  But not succeeded.  Also from CBroe comments says that it is not possible to access directly using FQL.

I solved this issue by using **Stream** table

```
SELECT post_id, viewer_id, app_id, source_id, updated_time, created_time, filter_key, attribution, actor_id, target_id, message, app_data, action_links, attachment, impressions, comments, likes, place, privacy, permalink, xid, tagged_ids, message_tags, description, description_tags, type FROM stream WHERE source_id  = me() and created_time > 1300904400
```

Response Json is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
.....
            "post_id": "10003422343219_2395933333495184",
            "viewer_id": 10034243333333519,
            "app_id": null,
            "tagged_ids": [],
            "message_tags": [],
            **"description": "Owner is now friends with Friend1 and Friend2.",**
            "description_tags": {
                "0": [
                    {
                        "id": 100003344233319,
                        "name": "Owner Name",
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 14,
                        "type": "user"
                    }
                ],
                "35": [
                    {
                        "id": 10000133333697,
                        "name": "Friend Name1",
                        "offset": 35,
                        "length": 10,
                        "type": "user"
                    }
                ],
                "50": [
                    {
                        "id": 10000444443615,
                        "name": "Frined Name2",
                        "offset": 50,
                        "length": 13,
                        "type": "user"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": null
        }
    ]
}
```

By using Description message we can identify the newly created friend.  'description_tags' consist of newly added friends list.